# Is there some $M \geq 0$ such that $|T(x)| \leq M|x|$ for all $x$?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, inequality

Let $T: \mathbb{R}^{m} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be linear. Is there some $M \geq 0$ such that $|T(x)| \leq M|x|$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$? I am not sure, as I just found a bound not that sharp.

Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^{m}$; let $[T]$ be the matrix of $T$ with respect to standard ordered bases; and let $A := \sup_{i,j} |[T]_{ij}|$. Then
$$
|T(x)| = |[T]x| = |(\sum_{1}^{m}[T]_{1j}x_{j}, \dots, \sum_{1}^{m}[T]_{nj}x_{j})| = |\sum_{1}^{m}([T]_{1j}x_{j}, \dots, [T]_{nj}x_{j})| \leq \sum_{1}^{m}|([T]_{1j}x_{j}, \dots, [T]_{nj}x_{j})| = \sum_{j=1}^{m}(\sum_{i=1}^{n}[T]_{ij}^{2}x_{j}^{2})^{1/2} \leq |A|n^{1/2}\sum_{1}^{m}|x_{j}|.
$$

So is it possible to improve this bound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case $T$ is normal the best bound possible is the maximum of the absolute values of the complex eigenvalues of $T$. Do you see why?

In general the best bound possible might be bigger.

**Edit:** The existence is easy: Consider $x\mapsto |T(x)|$ for all $x$ with norm 1. The function is continuous and defined on a compact set, so it attains a maximum. The maximum is due to linearity if $T$ your best bound possible (in particular it's finite).

Comment: Thank you. But, verily, I just would like to prove that one can majorize $|T(x)|$ in terms of $|x|$, so...

Comment: @Chou See my edit.

Comment: Thank you. But $T$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}^{m}$, instead of a compact set.

Comment: @Chou But the map I use in the proof is defined on a compact set (all $x\in\mathbb R^m$ with $|x|=1$).

Comment: Alright. Thank you, friend.

Answer (score 0):

In case that $T$ is continuous then it is bounded, i.e. there exists $M$ as you said.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_operator

The smallest one is the induced operator norm (which depends on the norm you consider for $x$),
\begin{equation}
\|T\| = \sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Tx\|.
\end{equation}

Comment: The crucial thing here is that all linear maps from $\mathbb R^n$ are continuous and hence bounded.

Comment: Yeah, That's true.